# DAX: count distinct values in a measure using two tables with filters in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need a measure that counts distinct records from a table related to another table via ID with filters on both sides. I have looked everywhere for answers, but none seemed to be close enough to what I'm trying to achieve in Power BI.

I'm not sure if I need the RELATED or the FILTER function. If I do, I'm not sure where to place it. Just for the record, PBI is relatively new to me.

```
Referrals = 
VAR StartDate = [Start Date]
VAR EndDate = [End Date]
VAR Result =
    CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Enrollments'[ClientID] ),
        ALL ( Dates[Date] ),
        'Enrollments'[EnrollmentDate] <= EndDate                -- count active clients
            && (                                                -- where the end date variable is less than or equal to enrollment date 
                'Enrollments'[DischargeDate] >= StartDate       -- and the discharge date is greater than the start date variable
                    || 'Enrollments'[DischargeDate] = BLANK ()  -- or the discharge date is blank
            )
            && 'Referrals'[Description] = "Employment Services"
    )
RETURN
    Result
```

[image]

Any insight is appreciated!